# npm not installing properly when brew install node

Tags: node.js, terminal, xterm

Im getting the following error, which I beleive is a permission error when trying to do brew install node. npm is not being installed properly. Any ideas?

```
⚙  /usr/local/bin
 ⚙ /usr/local/bin   master  brew install node
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/node-0.10.33_1
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/node-0.10.33_1.yosemite.bottle.10.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-0.10.33_1.yosemite.bottle.10.tar.gz
==> Caveats
If you update npm itself, do NOT use the npm update command.
The upstream-recommended way to update npm is:
  npm install -g npm@latest
==> make uninstall
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.33_1/libexec/npm/npm-debug.log
make: *** [uninstall] Error 3
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.33_1: 2081 files, 21M
 ✘ /usr/local/bin   master  brew postinstall node
==> make uninstall
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.33_1/libexec/npm/npm-debug.log
make: *** [uninstall] Error 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Try: `$sudo brew install node`